# What are the necessary steps required for conducting a Wolfowitz runs test of randomness, given that I have all the necessary data?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, statistical-significance, randomness, runs

I am writing a part in my thesis about the random-walk theory of price changes. I plan to set up a runs test of randomness to show whether the price changes do follow a particular random pattern. I have computed the number of runs for each '+' or '-' movement, and the number of observations is 15,000 and shown that it is a normal distribution. I have read that this can be done using a one-tail test and I plan to use a significance level of 5%.

However, the library I am using to test this doesn't appear to be working properly. So my question is, what are the steps of conducting this test so I can show the calculations as they happen?

Comment: See this wiki article.. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wald%E2%80%93Wolfowitz_runs_test

Comment: I have already look at this but it doesn't necessarily outline the methodology of the test steps, just the equations.